# How do you clone a drive encrypted with Filevault2?

Tags: macos, backup, filevault

Say I have drive A that is already encrypted with Filevault2.  I want to make an exact clone of the drive to a different drive B.  Every way I've tried so far decrypts drive A first, then clones, resulting in drive B being decrypted when the clone completes.  Is there a better way to clone drive A bit for bit?  I'm thinking of using `dd` but was wondering if there was a more Apple friendly way.

The best way I've been able to figure out how to do this so far:

1. Boot to a Lion install USB drive.
2. Open Disk Utility & unlock the encrypted drive
3. Format the new drive
4. Restore the encrypted volume on your new drive.  It will be unencrypted.
5. Close disk utility & open Terminal.
6. In Terminal, type "diskutil cs convert /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/".
7. Boot up to the new drive, open System Preferences, & re-enable encryption.  All previous settings should still be there.

I have not fully tested this method, but in theory it should work.  It's too many steps for my liking though.  I'd prefer one clone & be done with it, somehow.

Comment: "Every way I've tried" would be what exactly? There is no reason in having people here proposing solutions you've already tried...

Comment: The standard battery of methods:  Disk Utility w/ it's default options enabled, Carbon Copy Cloner, SuperDuper.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the recovery option of Disk Utility:

[image]

This of course requires source and target disk to be identical, but the same restriction applies to `dd` and similar tools.

**Usual warnings concerning picking the right disk as source etc. apply!**

Comment: Assume the destination disk is smaller.  Is that a problem for this method?

Comment: Yes, as with dd etc.